# Using D3.js to get the a magnetic effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

Which is the best way to get an effect like the one on this site http://archive.revolutionsinsound.com/#/explore/clubnights/lost ? 
I am trying to get this effect using D3.js, is there any other library that would yield the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

That's a force graph effect, which is can be draw with d3js, here's an example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

You can also search for other libraries using keywords like [force graph], and there's some other solutions: 
springy.js, or arborjs

Or you can just implement one by yourself, by controlling each frame rendering and the force between subjects.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions. Just to add to that question, I want to display the force effect on a Map. which is the best possible way to do that..?

Comment: @varun My choice would be leaflet to do the map work and d3js to draw force graph.